# IOS: knowing if the uiwebview has stopped scrolling

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Is it possible to know if the uiwebview has stopped scrolling? I checked the webview delegate but could not find a method.

Answer (score 2):

UIWebView has a `scrollView` property. UIScrollView gives delegate messages about scrolling.